# How to select data between hex values from a file

Tags: script, hexadecimal

Let my try and rephrase the question.

Below is a sample of the file I have, pasted from a hex editor.

```
0000:0000 | 02 30 1C 31  32 33 1C 49  72 72 65 6C  65 76 61 6E | .0.123.Irrelevan
0000:0010 | 74 20 41 53  43 49 49 20  44 61 74 61  1C 1C 1C 2F | t ASCII Data.../
0000:0020 | 1C 30 30 30  30 1C 1C 1C  1C 1C 1C 1C  30 30 30 1C | .0000.......000.
0000:0030 | 1C 1C 1C 38  31 32 37 30  1C 30 30 30  30 30 30 30 | ...81270.0000000
0000:0040 | 30 30 30 30  34 1C 1C 49  72 72 65 6C  65 76 61 6E | 00004..Irrelevan
0000:0050 | 74 20 41 53  43 49 49 20  44 61 74 61  1C 1C 32 1C | t ASCII Data..2.
0000:0060 | 1C 1C 30 30  1C 1C 1C 1C  34 34 30 1C  30 30 1C 06 | ..00....440.00..
0000:0070 | 02 58 52 1C  32 1C 53 57  31 77 62 33  4A 30 59 57 | .XR.2.SW1wb3J0YW
0000:0080 | 34 67 52 47  46 30 59 53  42 55 62 79  42 79 5A 58 | 4gRGF0YSBUbyByZX
0000:0090 | 52 79 61 57  56 32 5A 51  3D 3D 03 3A  34 06 02 58 | RyaWV2ZQ==.:4..X
0000:00A0 | 41 1C 32 1C  30 03 3E 37  06 02 59 52  1C 33 1C 37 | A.2.0.>7..YR.3.7
0000:00B0 | 03 3F 33 06  02 59 41 1C  33 1C 30 1C  51 57 35 76 | .?3..YA.3.0.QW5v
0000:00C0 | 64 47 68 6C  63 69 42 4A  62 58 42 76  63 6E 52 68 | dGhlciBJbXBvcnRh
0000:00D0 | 62 69 42 45  59 58 52 68  49 46 52 76  49 48 4A 6C | biBEYXRhIFRvIHJl
0000:00E0 | 64 48 4A 70  5A 58 5A 6C  03 3E 36 06  02 59 52 1C | dHJpZXZl.>6..YR.
0000:00F0 | 34 1C 31 31  32 39 03 3C  38 06 02 59  41 1C 34 1C | 4.1129.<8..YA.4.
0000:0100 | 30 1C 51 57  35 6B 49 48  6C 6C 64 43  42 74 62 33 | 0.QW5kIHlldCBtb3
0000:0110 | 4A 6C 49 47  6C 74 63 47  39 79 64 47  46 75 49 45 | JlIGltcG9ydGFuIE
0000:0120 | 52 68 64 47  45 67 56 47  38 67 63 6D  56 30 63 6D | RhdGEgVG8gcmV0cm
0000:0130 | 6C 6C 64 6D  55 3D 03 0A                           | lldmU=..
```

Each piece of data is preceded with hex value of `1C` and end in hex value `03`.

I need a method to extract the data between `1C` and `03` delimiters and export them into an ASCII file, each piece of data on a separate line.

I can't use the `cut` utility, since the file doesn't have a structure to select certain "fields".

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/linux/binary-files-pattern-search

Comment: Still not clear what you want to achieve. Highlight an example from the dump that you want to extract

Comment: @Nifle thank you for the link. I did learn something new, but not quite what I was looking for.
My end goal is to extract all Base64 encoded pieces of data. But as long as I can extract all piece of data between `1C` and `03` I don't mind doing some manual work.
So let's take string "SW1wb3J0YW4gRGF0YSBUbyByZXRyaWV2ZQ==" for example.
This piece of data starts on line 8 (0070) and ends on line 10 (0090). To identify where actual data starts I need to find hex value `1C` and to identify where actual data ends I need to find hex value `03` and then copy everything in between `1C` and `03`.

Comment: untested `data | hexdump | sed 's/1C/\nX/g' | sed 's/03/X\n/' | grep '^X.*X$' | tr -d 'X'` should hopefully give you the data between 1C and 03 in hex format

Comment: @Nifle thank you, that is a neat idea.
It didn't work for me, but I get the thinking behind it. I'll try to play around with your idea, see what I can get out of it.

Comment: Just wanted to leave a quick comment. Nifle's ideas was correct. The only thing is that file output does not need to go though hexdup, so actual command is `cat path/to/binary.file | sed 's/1C/\nX/g' | sed 's/03/X\n/' | grep '^X.*X$' | tr -d 'X'`

Otherwise hexdump converts hex values into their ASCII representation and "sed" can no longer find hex values.